# Removing some letters from a string in matlab

Tags: regex, matlab

I have a string like this `ID="MOD09GA.A2008077.h00v08.005.2008080115153.hdf.xml"`

I want to remove some numbers from the string.

I want this `" MOD09GA.A2008077.h00v08.hdf"`

I know i can use `regexp(ID, '".hdf"', 'match')`

How can i do it in  Matlab ?

How can i remove additional numbers?

Thank you in advance

Comment: What is the criterion to decide which parts you want to remove? Parts consisting in only numbers plus the final part?

Comment: is not it clear? i want to remove [.005.2008080115153.xml] just with regexp. plz help

Comment: No, it's not clear at all. You provide an _example_, but what is the _rule_?

Comment: There is a duplicate (but you posted it before). See the other question for a regexp answer:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24982393/downloading-data-from-website-in-matlab

Answer (score 3):

You might want to look into [`strsplit`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/strsplit.html) and [`strjoin`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/strjoin.html):

```
C = strsplit( ID, '.' );
newID = strjoin( C([1 2 3 6]), '.' );
```

Alternatively, you can use `regexp` and `sprintf`:

```
C = regexp( ID, '\.', 'split' );
newID = sprintf('%s.', C{[1 2 3 6]} );
newID(end) = []; % discard of trailing '.'
```