# Downloading data from website

Tags: regex, matlab

I use the following code for downloading two files in a folder from a website.

I want to download some files that contain "MOD09GA.A2008077.h22v05.005.2008080122814.hdf" and "MOD09GA.A2008077.h23v05.005.2008080122921.hdf" in the page. But I don't know how to select these files. The code below download all the files, but I only need two of them.

Does anyone have any ideas?

```
URL = 'http://e4ftl01.cr.usgs.gov/MOLT/MOD09GA.005/2008.03.17/';
% Local path on your machine
localPath = 'E:/myfolder/';

% Read html contents and parse file names with ending *.hdf
urlContents = urlread(URL);
ret = regexp(urlContents, '"\S+.hdf.xml"', 'match');


% Loop over all files and download them
for k=1:length(ret)
    filename = ret{k}(2:end-1);
    filepathOnline = strcat(URL, filename);
    filepathLocal = fullfile(localPath, filename);
    urlwrite(filepathOnline, filepathLocal);
end
```

Comment: Your regexp string seems to have a problem. Shouldn't it be `\S+\.hdf\.xml`? The two extra backslashes are for escaping `.` which should be separators for file name and extension.

Comment: `ret = regexp(urlContents, '"MOD09GA\.A2008077\.h22v05\.005\.[0-9]+\.hdf\.xml"', 'match');` is this what you want?

Comment: No, it dose not work.i want to delete "005.2008080115153" from this ID "MOD09GA.A2008077.h00v08.005.2008080115153.hdf.xml. plz help

Comment: That's your another question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24979893/removing-some-letters-from-a-string-in-matlab

Answer (score 2):

Try the regexp with `tokens` instead:

```
localPath = 'E:/myfolder/';
urlContents = 'aaaa "MOD09GA.A2008077.h22v05.005.2008080122814.hdf.xml" and "MOD09GA.A2008077.h23v05.005.2008080122921.hdf.xml"  aaaaa';

ret = regexp(urlContents , '"(\S+)(?:\.\d+){2}(\.hdf\.xml)"', 'tokens');
%// Loop over each file name
for k=1:length(ret)
    filename = [ret{k}{:}];
    filepathLocal = fullfile(localPath, filename)
end
```

Comment: 1) a typo in `tokens` 2) should it be `[ret{k,:}]`?

Comment: 1) What typo? 2) No, there is only 1 dimension

Comment: So `[ret{k}{:}]` or `[ret{k}]`?

Comment: Ha, yes it should be k, not 1. It's one dimension, but then it's nested with another so as it is is correct. ret{k} are all parts of filename k. Whereas ret{k}{:} will expand them.

Comment: there is below error why?:                                                   Error in ==> fullfile at 39                                       elseif (f(end)==fs) || (part(1)==fs || (bIsPC && (f(end)=='/' || part(1)=='/')) )